# Is it possible to use IDiaDataSource::LoadDataFromPdb to read pdbs from symbol store?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, msdn, dia-sdk

I am trying to use `IDiaDataSource::LoadDataFromPdb` from Debug Interface Access 
windows library (DIA) to read symbol files (*.pdb) from the local symbol store but I do not find something to set the path which above function would use to search for *.pdbs. Is it possible for `LoadDataForPdb` to read symbols files from local symbol store?

Local symbol store is created by using the tool `SymStore.exe` with the following command line arguments:

`symstore.exe add /f *.pdb /s .\SymbolStore /t "X"`

Local symbol store contains all the pdbs in a centralized place.

Comment: It is not clear what "local symbol store" might mean.  There is no oracle that provides a symbol cache directory.  The answer is probably in [this code](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb/blob/master/PDB/dbi/locator.cpp).

Comment: Thanks for reply but that link does not help since this question is specifically about windows DIA library. I have updated the question to reflect how local symbol store is created, please see above and please let me know if you have any knowledge of this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [`IDiaSession::findInjectedSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/idiasession-findinjectedsource):

> Retrieves a list of sources that has been placed into the symbol store by attribute providers or other components of the compilation process.

You can probably load a .pdb file directly from the symbol store using [`IDiaDataSource::loadDataFromPdb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/idiadatasource-loaddatafrompdb) if you have the indexed .pdb path, but I guess the former is more suitable.